# How to fit image according to width and height in bootstrap card?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to give image width and height(300px;300px;) in card:

```
<!-- Card Start From Here -->
  <div class="card" style="width: 35rem;">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="/demo/img/1.jpeg" alt="Card image cap" style="width:35rem;height:20rem;"/>
   <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Card Start From Here -->
```

The output has shrunk:

[image]

If I remove below line of code then the image will be so long but does not shrink:

```
style="width:35rem;height:20rem;"
```

I have tried:

```
object-fit:cover;(Check all properties like fill, scale-down)
```

Also tried some CSS:

```
<style>
 .clsAutofit{
   height:300px;
   width:300px;
  }
 .clsImg{
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  }
 </style>

 <div class="clsAutofit">
   <img src="/demo/img/1.jpeg" class="clsImg" />
 </div> 
 <!-- This also not working in card -->
```

I also tried some properties:

```
<style>
 img.one {
 display: block;
 object-fit: contain;
 max-width:500px;
 max-height:280px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 }

 img.two {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 535px;;
  height: 535px;
  }
 .box {
   width: 30%;
   height: 200px;
   border: 5px dashed #f7a239;
 }
 .containerTY {
    width: 60%;
    height: 500px;
 }
 .containerTYZ {
    max-width: 100%;
 }
 .thumbnail {
   width: 500px;
   height: 400px;
  }
 .img4R {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50vw;
  }
 </style>
```

I tried but not able to make it yet.
Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using `img-fluid` for image and you also use `w-25 w-50 w-100` for `lg`,`md`,`sm` etc devices

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .w-md-50{width:50% !important;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .w-lg-75{width:75% !important;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-5 w-100 mx-auto">
        
        <!-- Card Start From Here -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card p-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-lg-75 w-md-50 w-100 text-center" src="https://i.ibb.co/Xyk1kJy/1-1.jpg" alt="Card image cap"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="card-body px-0 pb-0">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Card Start From Here -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card p-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-lg-75 w-md-50 w-100 text-center" src="https://i.ibb.co/Xyk1kJy/1-1.jpg" alt="Card image cap"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="card-body px-0 pb-0">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card end From Here -->

        <!-- Card Start From Here -->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card p-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-lg-75 w-md-50 w-100 text-center" src="https://i.ibb.co/Xyk1kJy/1-1.jpg" alt="Card image cap"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="card-body px-0 pb-0">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Card end From Here --> 

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i adding answer to more.. wait somewhile

Comment: Updated answer try this and also check responsive without added any style css.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. You are the real camp! A very nice human who like to help the beginner. Thanks a lot for your precious time. The code is working fine but one problem: if I pass the url in src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/300068.jpg" the code working fine. But if I download the image in my project and give url path from local project folder like src="/demo/img/300068.jpg" then the image is again showing long. Strange but it happen with me. Can you check is it also happen with you? Download https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/300068.jpg and pass it locally.

Comment: sorry don't down that link. Download this image and pass locally https://ibb.co/1sJ1J2s

Comment: or pass this url directly https://i.ibb.co/Xyk1kJy/1-1.jpg

Comment: Check now . if any issue comment me

Comment: image is showing and not shrinking but showing only one side of the frame

Comment: please add screenshot for issue. I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

your approach is okay.problem is,bootstrap class attributes tend to have `!important`.

so place your custom style.css under your bootstrap.css so it gets more priority than bs,

then use:

```
.my-image{
  height : 300px !important;
  width: 300px !important
}
```

bind the image with class `.my-image`, clear **inline css styles**,and check this.

Comment: <img src="/demo/img/1.jpeg" class="my-image" /> I have used your solution but still the image has shrunk. Only the image frame got small 300x300

Answer (score 0):

```
 .clsImg{
  max-width:100%;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit:cover;
  }
```

Comment: not working. Kindly pass this url directly https://i.ibb.co/Xyk1kJy/1-1.jpg and check.

Comment: also give width and height 300ps;300px each the image will be shrink and if you remove css and width and height the image will be so long.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues.